# Summarize count of occurrences in an array of objects with Array#reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to summarize an array of objects and return the number of object occurrences in another array of objects. What is the best way to do this?

**From this**

```
var arrayOfSongs = [
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Green","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"}
];
```

**To this**

```
var newArrayOfSongs = [
  {"title": "Blue", "playCount": 3 },
  {"title": "Green", "playCount": 1}
]
```

**I have tried**

```
 arrayOfSongs.reduce(function(acc, cv) {
   acc[cv.title] = (acc[cv.title] || 0) + 1;
     return acc;
   }, {});
 }
```

But it returns an object:

```
 { "Blue": 3, "Green": 1};
```

Comment: "*I am trying...*" – and what did you try? How far did you get? What wrong? How did it go wrong?

Comment: Object -> array is easy using Object.keys and Array#map ... e.g. `Object.keys(obj).map(title => ({title, playCount:obj[title]}));`

Comment: It should be trivial to change that object into the array that you want, simply by iterating over the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the initial argument to the `reduce` function as an array instead of object and filter array for the existing value as below,

**Working snippet**:

```js
var arrayOfSongs = [
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Green","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"}
];


var newArrayOfSongs = arrayOfSongs.reduce(function(acc, cv) {
    var arr = acc.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.title === cv.title;
    });
   
    if(arr.length === 0) {
      acc.push({title: cv.title, playCount: 1});
    } else {
      arr[0].playCount += 1;
    }
    
    return acc;
   }, []);

console.log(newArrayOfSongs);
```

Answer (score 1):

To build on what you already have done, the next step is to "convert" the object to an array

```js
    var arrayOfSongs = [
        {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
        {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
        {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
        {"title":"Green","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"}
    ];

    var obj = arrayOfSongs.reduce(function(acc, cv) {
       acc[cv.title] = (acc[cv.title] || 0) + 1;
       return acc;
    }, {});

    // *** added code starts here ***
    var newArrayOfSongs = Object.keys(obj).map(function(title) { 
        return {
            title: title, 
            playCount:obj[title]
        };
    });

    console.log(newArrayOfSongs);
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing this in two stages. First, chunk the array by title, then map the chunks into the output you want. This will really help you in future changes. Doing this all in one pass is highly complex and will increase the chance of messing up in the future.

```
var arrayOfSongs = [
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Blue","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"},
  {"title":"Green","duration":161.71,"audioUrl":"/assets/music/blue","playing":false,"playedAt":"2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"}
];

function chunkByAttribute(arr, attr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, e) {
   acc[e[attr]] = acc[e[attr]] || [];
   acc[e[attr]].push(e);
   return acc;
  }, {});
}

var songsByTitle = chunkByAttribute(arrayOfSongs, 'title');

var formattedOutput = Object.keys(songsByTitle).map(function (title) {
  return {
    title: title,
    playCount: songsByTitle[title].length
  };
});
```

There, now everything is named according to what it does, everything does just one thing, and is a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/93e35wcq/

I used a set object to get the unique track titles, then used Array.map to splice those and return a song object that contains play count inside the track title.

The Data:

```
var arrayOfSongs = [{
  "title": "Blue",
  "duration": 161.71,
  "audioUrl": "/assets/music/blue",
  "playing": false,
  "playedAt": "2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"
}, {
  "title": "Blue",
  "duration": 161.71,
  "audioUrl": "/assets/music/blue",
  "playing": false,
  "playedAt": "2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"
}, {
  "title": "Blue",
  "duration": 161.71,
  "audioUrl": "/assets/music/blue",
  "playing": false,
  "playedAt": "2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"
}, {
  "title": "Green",
  "duration": 161.71,
  "audioUrl": "/assets/music/blue",
  "playing": false,
  "playedAt": "2016-12-21T22:58:55.203Z"
}];
```

The Function:

```
function getPlayCount(arrayOfSongs) {
  let songObj = {};
  let SongSet = new Set();
  arrayOfSongs.map(obj => (SongSet.has(obj.title)) ? true : SongSet.add(obj.title));
  for (let songTitle of SongSet.values()) {
    songObj[songTitle] = {
      playCount: 0
    };
    arrayOfSongs.map(obj => (obj.title === songTitle) ? songObj[songTitle].playCount++ : false)
  }
  return songObj;
}

console.log(getPlayCount(arrayOfSongs));
```

Which isn't exactly what you wanted formatting wise, but if you're married to it, this will do the trick:

```
    function getPlayCount(arrayOfSongs) {
  let songObj = {};
  let SongSet = new Set();
  arrayOfSongs.map(obj => (SongSet.has(obj.title)) ? true : SongSet.add(obj.title));
  for (let songTitle of SongSet.values()) {
    songObj[songTitle] = 0;
    arrayOfSongs.map(obj => (obj.title === songTitle) ? songObj[songTitle]++ : false)
  }
  return songObj;
}

console.log(getPlayCount(arrayOfSongs));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/93e35wcq/1/

Comment: why are you using `arrayOfSongs.map` twice where `arrayOfSongs.forEach` would be more appropriate as you don't use .map return value? and why is your result an Object, not an Array!!!